# Rails div not rendering?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple app I'm following from a textbook. It's a store app and on the oft side of the page a shopping cart is shown. However, when the cart is empty it is supposed to be hidden. So I wrote a helper function to hide the cart whenever it is empty. This would have been east enough just to do in the html but it's how the book shows it. It works mostly. If I empty the cart it stops being displayed, but when I first open the page the cart will be invisible even if its not empty! Adding an item to it will then reveal it.

Here's the code:

application.html.erb

```
<div id="cart">
        <% if @cart %>
         <% hidden_div_if( @cart.line_items.empty?, id:"cart" ) do %>
             <%= render @cart %>
         <% end %>
      <%end%>
</div>
```

application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

```
  def hidden_div_if(condition, attributes = {}, &block)
    debugger
    if(condition)
      attributes["style"] = "display: none"
    end
    content_tag("div", attributes, &block)
  end

end
```

Where I put the debugger statement, I checked the condition and it says it's false. So, I thin it's an issue with the html file. The controller sets the cart before hand with this code at the top.

```
      include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart
```

So, I'm not sure why it would show after a button is pressed but not on the initial page load. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Do you have a `@cart` at first? Is it `nil`? What does the resultant HTML look like? BTW, you don't want `id:"cart"` as that will give you two `<div id="cart">` elements and that's not valid HTML, choose another `id` for the inner `<div>` (or the outer one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with `<%=` in erb if you want to output the return value of a helper method. Change the line in which you call your helper method to:

```
<%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id: "cart") do %>
```

Comment: I just realized that for before checking the thread! haha. I confused my self because I'd seen if statements just using <% %>. thanks.